# Is there a glitch in the number of visitors count?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I bumped into [this page](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/), that says we’ve been having 5 visitors a day! 
[image]

---

[Area 51 page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language) says 4!

Ok, this was when I fists asked the question. Today both pages show 2 visitors a day! A couple of weeks ago it was thousands a day. So this low number has to be a glitch, right?

---

[stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#traffic) says 5.6k!

The actual number can be seen in SE statistics:

[image]

Comment: Prolly related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308966/208518).

Comment: Atualizei a tua pergunta, se não estiveres de acordo, podes reverter.

Comment: Today, our Site Stats reads:
1,474 questions
2,574 answers
96% answered
3,015 users
5,897 visitors/day      Does it really mean 5 thousand visitors?  Or is there a misprint and it means 5.897  ?

Comment: @Centaurus, It really is five thousand. For instance my questions and answers have reached one million views, or about a thousand a day on average. You wouldn't get that with five visitors a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Problem solved!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311989/218708)

[image]